# Setup script seems to be not running the install function

Tags: magento2, install-script, setup-upgrade

Here is my script:

```
<?php

namespace WatchUWant\ConfigSync\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\DefaultCategory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Store;
/*
class StoreObject extends Store {

}
*/

//include('/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php');
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{


    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

     $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

//  $connection = $installer->getConnection();

    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 // $storeModel=$om->get('Magento\Store\Model\Store');

        $i=0;
        $code_found=false;
        $key_not_found=false;
/*        while($code_found == false && $key_not_found==false)  {

            $storeModel->load($i);

            $code = $storeModel->getCode();

            if ($code == 'hong-kong')   {
                $code_found=true;
            }

            if(empty($code))    {
                $key_not_found=true;
            }   else    {
                $i++;
        }
        }
   */     


   // GROUP (STORE) ARRAY Array ( [website_id] => 1 [name] => Hong Kong Store [root_category_id] => 2 [group_id] => )

    $group_array = Array();
    $group_array['group']= Array('website_id'=>'1','name'=>'Honk Kong','root_category_id'=>'2','group_id'=>'');


    $group_array['group']['name'] = $this->filterManager->removeTags($group_array['group']['name']);
    /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\Group $groupModel */
    $groupModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Group');


    $all_stores=$group_model->getStores();

    $already_added=false;
/*  foreach ($all_stores as $a_store)   {
        if($a_store['code']=='hong_kong')   {
            $already_added=true;
        }
    }
*/  
//  if($already_added==false)   {

        if ($group_array['group']['group_id']) {
            $groupModel->load($group_array['group']['group_id']);
        }
        $groupModel->setData($group_array['group']);
        if ($group_array['group']['group_id'] == '') {
            $groupModel->setId(null);
        }
        if (!$this->isSelectedDefaultStoreActive($group_array, $groupModel)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('An inactive store view cannot be saved as default store view')
            );
        }
        $groupModel->save();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('store_group_save', ['group' => $groupModel]);
//      $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the store.'));

        // END GROUP

        // STORE VIEW ARRAY group_id (store), name, code, is_active, sort_order

        $store_ids = $groupModel->getStoreIds();

        $group_id= max($store_ids);

        $store_array = Array();
        $store_array['store']= Array('group_id'=>$group_id,'name'=>'Honk Kong','code'=>'hong_kong_view','is_active'=>'1','sort_order'=>'0','store_id'=>'');


        $eventName = 'store_edit';
        /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\Store $storeModel */
        $storeModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store');
        $store_array['store']['name'] = $this->filterManager->removeTags($store_array['store']['name']);
        if ($store_array['store']['store_id']) {
            $storeModel->load($store_array['store']['store_id']);
        }
        $storeModel->setData($store_array['store']);
        if ($store_array['store']['store_id'] == '') {
            $storeModel->setId(null);
            $eventName = 'store_add';
        }
        $groupModel = $this->_objectManager->create(
            'Magento\Store\Model\Group'
        )->load(
            $storeModel->getGroupId()
        );
        $storeModel->setWebsiteId($groupModel->getWebsiteId());
        if (!$storeModel->isActive() && $storeModel->isDefault()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('The default store cannot be disabled')
            );
        }
        $storeModel->save();
        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager')->reinitStores();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch($eventName, ['store' => $storeModel]);
//      $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the store view.'.));

            //END STORE VIEW
//      }

   /*
    $postData['website']['name'] = $this->filterManager->removeTags($postData['website']['name']);
    $websiteModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Website');
    if ($postData['website']['website_id']) {
        $websiteModel->load($postData['website']['website_id']);
    }
    $websiteModel->setData($postData['website']);
    if ($postData['website']['website_id'] == '') {
        $websiteModel->setId(null);
    }

    $websiteModel->save();

*/
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

But is doesn't seem to be running the install function in that class. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the file name from "installData.php" to "installSchema.php"